# Deterministic and non-deterministic Gaussian maps

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I came to the above two terms in a quantum information paper dealing with Gaussian states and Gaussian channels. First I thought that, by non-determinism, the output is actually a probability distribution. But by definition, channels sends states (which are probability distribution in a non-commutative space) to states. But then there is no deterministic channels.

Kindly help me to understand these two terms in this scenario. I also could not relate it with deterministic and non-deterministic automata theory.

Comment: Can you provide links?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05285

Comment: According to what's written in the paper, deterministic means trace-preserving.

Comment: However, I thought all quantum channels are completely positive trace preserving maps! It is not clear to me whether they are preserving trace of covariance matrix. Any idea?